# How to sort parent table data based on their reference count in child table using LINQ c#?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to sort parent table by their reference count(a foreign key) in another child table. Suppose

The parentTbl

- Id
- Name

ChildTbl

- Id
- parentId
- detials

I want to select only the parentTbl columns sorted by their reference count in ChildTbl by joining them like bellow:

```
var parents = from p in context.parentTbl
          join c in context.ChildTbl on p.Id equals c.parentId
          orderby count(c.parentId)
          select distinct p;
```

I think I also need to group them before ordering but I am not sure how to achieve this.

**Note: There is no navigational parent child property. Just a foreign key in the child table(that I mentioned) and I want to count by that foreign key column**

Comment: Show your model classes, LINQ query is built from classes and their navigation properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check this out.

```
// Query the parentTbl table and join it to the childTbl table
var query = from p in parentTbl
            join c in (
               from c2 in childTbl
               group c2 by c2.parentId into g
               select new { parentId = g.Key, referenceCount = g.Count() }
            ) on p.Id equals c.parentId
            orderby c.referenceCount descending
            select p;

// Execute the query and print the sorted records
foreach (var p in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}: {p.ReferenceCount} references");
}
```

and the SQL version

```
 SELECT p.*
FROM parentTbl p
JOIN (
   SELECT parentId, COUNT(*) AS referenceCount
   FROM childTbl
   GROUP BY parentId
) AS c ON p.Id = c.parentId
ORDER BY c.referenceCount DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps ?

```
// sort parents by number of children using linq
   var sortedParents = from p in parents
                       join c in children on p.id equals c.parentId into pc
                       orderby pc.Count() descending
                       select new { parent = p, children = pc };
```

Comment: It will not. `GroupJoin` has very limited translation in EF Core.

Comment: I see, well could this be a better option ? :
`var sortedParents = parents.OrderBy(p => children.Count(c => c.parentId == p.id));`

Comment: Do not do group join but `orderby children.Where(c => c.parentId == p.Id).Count() descending`